# Среда для UML-моделирования.

Tags: uml, ide

Просьба посоветовать, какую среду лучше использовать для моделирования UML. Точней даже рассказать, какой пользовались Вы и какие плюсы-минусы, удобства-неудобства были Вами замечены. Сам я кроме `rational rose` ничего в глаза не видел. Хотелось бы ознакомиться со всеми средами, какие на данный момент есть. Желательно, чтобы они были бесплатными, но не обязательно. Гуглить можно долго, но Вам, коллеги, я доверяю больше. Поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу посоветовать visual paradigm for uml, есть интеграция с IDE, сами использовали при разработке проекта на пхп. Из этой же серии enterprise architect. Но первая пошустрее и поприятнее будет

Answer (score 3):

rational rose - достаточно "тяжелый" проект, для простого моделирования есть много обычных редакторов от встроенных в IDE языков программирования до Microsoft Visio. Из альтернатив: StarUML, UML Pad, UML Studio.

Comment: А из встраиваемых в NetBeans какие-то конкретные можешь посоветовать? Пользовался вообще сам?

Answer (score 1):

Если есть возможность себе позволить, то EA и VP очень хороши. ЕА при этом еще достаточно недорог.

Из бесплатных, на мой взгляд, самое адекватное и удобное - StarUML. Вторым в списке, пожалуй, PoseidonUML.

Для суровых любителей академического LaTeX-а еще есть metauml.

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Architect попробуй, она платная, thepiratebay.org тебе в помощь

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, все зависит от того, на каком уровне вам нужно проводить построение uml-диаграмм. От этого зависит объем необходимого под рукой инструментария.

Для построения диаграмм последовательностей, классов, вариантов использования и еще каких-нибудь, входящих в список базовых, могу порекомендовать онлайн-инструмент **Draw.io.**

Это бесплатный сервис, который предоставляет удобный интерфейс для быстрого, еще раз обращу внимания быстрого!!! создания диаграмм, которые можно тут же сохранить себе на носитель в XML, или сохранить в сессии браузера, или в облаке.

В доступных элементах есть все виды стрелок, блоков, готовые шаблоны для проектирования сущностей БД.

Хоть IDE и не является, но тоже достойный вариант для создания диаграмм на лету.